# Robustness checks for fixed effects model

Tags: r, regression, fixed-effects-model, f-test, plm

So I'm estimating a fixed effects model using `plm` that looks at the effects of immigrants on house prices in different districts over several years. And I was wondering what type of robustness check can I do to support the findings of this `plm` model? (Btw I'm using a within estimator with a twoways effect for district and year)

Would estimating different types of prices be considered a good robustness check? e.g looking at house prices and apartment prices